# How can i find the annualized Interest Rate for borrowing a stock?

Tags: united-states, stocks

How can i find the Annualized Interest Rate for borrowing a stock ?

Comment: Borrowing a stock is a futures contract on it, right? Since you can't predict what the market will do, you can't predict an exact APR equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "borrow" a stock is to sell it short, which is extremely risky. Selling a security short requires a margin agreement, the rate will be determined by your brokerage firm's margin interest rates.